# Реализация алгоритма Сапера

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Наткнулся в интернете на реализацию сапера, но сразу понял, что работает он немного не так, как нужно. 
(А точнее открывает с одного клика почти все поле)
[image]

Пытался сам исправить, но все тщетно.
Вот сам код реализации открытие полей.
...

Вот так реализуется раставление мин

```cpp
#define FIELD_X 19
#define FIELD_Y 19
 int field[FIELD_X][FIELD_Y];


void putMines()  //Рандомно раскладываем мины
{

    for(int z=0;z<MINES_COUNT;z++)
    {
        field[1+rand()%(FIELD_X-2)][1+rand()%(FIELD_Y-2)]=9;
    }

}
```

Вот так реализуется прорисовка клеток

```cpp
        app.clear(sf::Color(255,255,255));


        for(int yqwe = 1; yqwe <= (FIELD_Y-2); yqwe+=1)  //В цикле проходим все клетки и рисуем их с соответствующей позицией

        {

            for(int zqwe = 1; zqwe <= (FIELD_X-2); zqwe+=1)

            {

                if (opened[zqwe][yqwe])  //Если клетка открыта рисуем значение

                {

                switch (field[zqwe][yqwe])  //В зависимости от значения клетки выбираем нужный участок текстуры

                {

                    case 1: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,30,30)); break;}

                    case 2: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(31,0,61,30)); break;}

                    case 3: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(62,0,92,30)); break;}

                    case 4: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(93,0,123,30)); break;}

                    case 5: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(124,0,154,30)); break;}

                    case 6: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(155,0,185,30)); break;}

                    case 9: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(217,0,247,30)); break;}

                    case 0: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(248,0,278,30)); break;}

                    case 10: {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(186,0,216,30)); break;}


                }

                } else {sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(186,0,216,30));}  //Иначе рисуем флажок

                sprite.setPosition((zqwe-1)*30,(yqwe-1)*30);

                app.draw(sprite);


            }

        }

        app.draw(exit.button);

        app.draw(exit.text);

        app.draw(newGame.button);

        app.draw(newGame.text);

        app.draw(settings.button);

        app.draw(settings.text);

        if (settingsWindow)

        {

        app.draw(setWin.title);

        app.draw(setWin.leftBorder);

        app.draw(setWin.rightBorder);

        app.draw(setWin.botBorder);

        app.draw(setWin.body);

        }

        if (lose)

        {

        app.draw(loseWin.title);

        app.draw(loseWin.leftBorder);

        app.draw(loseWin.rightBorder);

        app.draw(loseWin.botBorder);

        app.draw(loseWin.body);

        }

        app.display();
```

Comment: "Почти все поле" - это как? Вот на скрине в центре поля почти нет мин. Может поэтому и кажется, что он слишком много открывает?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Проблема в том, что он открывает больше, чем нужно. На скрине показано, что я всего лишь одним кликом открыл почти все поля, и даже те поля, которые вообще не должны были открываться.

Comment: А как у вас описано игровое поле? Какие значения могут находиться в массиве `field`?

Comment: @trollingchar  Ну сначала обнуляется поле, после рандомно раскладываются мины и проставляются цифры.

Comment: @Клешня я хотел чат создать, но не могу пригласить вас почему-то, поэтому напишу так. Как вы использовали мою функцию? Не помещали ли вы ее внутрь циклов? В каком массиве хранятся цифры у вас?

Comment: @trollingchar Вашей функцией я просто заменил старую. Внутрь циклов я ее не помещал. И хотел бы уточнить, о каких цифрах идёт речь?

Comment: @Клешня речь о цифрах, которые обозначают количество мин, и я так понял, сама мина обозначается числом 9. Я полагаю, это массив `field`. Было бы неплохо отладчиком посмотреть или хотя бы просто вывести координаты открываемых клеток и цифру в них. И да, возможно баг в отображении, типа неоткрытые клетки отобразятся как открытые. Можете код отображения ячеек добавить?

Comment: @trollingchar Добавил код.

Answer (score 0):

Задача открывания клетки в сапере (в том числе соседних клеток) решается примерно так:

```
void open(int x, int y) {
    // проверка на выход за границы:
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || x >= height) return;

    // если открыта мина, то игра кончается
    if (field[x][y] == MINE) {
        game_over();
        return;
    }

    // предотвращение бесконечной рекурсии: если клетка открыта, ничего не делаем
    if (opened[x][y]) return;

    // открываем клетку
    opened[x][y] = true;

    // и если нет мин рядом, то и все соседние через эту же функцию
    // если и там нет мин, они откроют уже свои соседние
    if (field[x][y] == 0) {
        open(x-1, y-1); open(x, y-1); open(x+1, y-1);
        open(x-1, y  );               open(x+1, y  );
        open(x-1, y+1); open(x, y+1); open(x+1, y+1);
    }
}
```

Обходить все поле да еще и с циклом на 600 итераций *"про запас"* - нелогичное решение, к тому же и неэффективное.

Comment: Попробовал вашу функцию, но проблема никуда не пропала. Видимо, проблема не в реализации открытия полей. Буду разбираться.

Comment: А разве в стандартном варианте соседями считаются диагональные?

Comment: @MBo да, диагональные считаются.

Comment: @Клешня возможно, ошибка в том месте где вычисляется количество мин в соседних клетках. Это бы объяснило почему везде нули.